# How to pattern-match an intermediate value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

## Question

In the book *Category Theory for Programmers* by Bartosz Milewski, chapter 4.3.

You must code a Kleisli category where morphisms are partial functions. Here is my attempt which does not compile:

```
data Optional a = Valid a | Invalid deriving (Show)

return :: a -> Optional a
return x = Valid x

(>=>) :: (a -> Optional b) -> (b -> Optional c) -> (a -> Optional c)
f (>=>) g = \x ->
    let s = f x
    in | s == Valid v = g v
       | s == Invalid = Invalid
```

In the `>=>` operator definition, I want to pattern-match the intermediate value `s` to test if is `Valid` (and then call `f`) or if it is `Invalid` (and then return `Invalid`). How can I do this ?

Comment: I think first things first your should condiser making Optional type an instance of Monad type class and then the Kleisli composition operator would come free of charge `f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g`.

Comment: I will try this later Redu, the point of the book is to gradually learn how to apply category theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `case` to do pattern matching:

```
f >=> g = \x ->
  case f x of
    Valid v -> g v
    Invalid -> Invalid
```

In your question you also seem to be trying to use guards for pattern matching and binding values. Haskell does not allow this. A guard is just a boolean valued expression which must be true for the preceding (sometimes optional) pattern to match. Haskell the language doesn’t really “understand” the `(==)` operator as meaning equality. It just sees it as a function like any other. And indeed one can define it for a type to not correspond to the same kind of equality that a pattern match requires.

A guard is allowed to use variables from the pattern (or from a larger scope) but can’t bind new ones like a pattern. Therefore this would be wrong because `v` would be undefined.

```
f >=> g = \x ->
  case f x of
    _ | x == Valid v -> g v
    _ | x == Invalid -> Invalid
```

It would also make it basically impossible for the compiler to ever know if your patterns are exhaustive (ie that there are no values which wouldn’t be matched by any case)

Comment: In a sense, `case` is the fundamental tool of destructuring in Haskell, in that other pattern matching desugars into `case` statements in the core language. So it is good to get a handle on it.

Comment: OK, so the guards is a syntax sugar in the particular situation where the case is applied to an argument of a function, right ?

Comment: @vkubicki I don’t understand what you mean. What do you think a guard is? What do you think it’s syntactic sugar for?

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions there is section called guards

Comment: I thought that guards were used for pattern-matching, but it seems there are only used to perform tests on values.