# Changing a do expression that uses pattern matching to application of the bind operator

Tags: haskell, monads

### Original question

[LYAH, in *For a Few Monads More*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) shows this function,

```hs
solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double  
solveRPN st = do  
    [result] <- foldM foldingFunction [] (words st)  
    return result
```

which uses pattern-matching in conjunction with `do` expression **to esure that the monad coming out of `foldM` wraps a singleton list**.

In order to truly understand the nature of the `do` expression as well as of `Monad`, I have been rewriting most example from that book using `>>=` and `>>` instead of the `do` expression, a practice which is suggested somewhere in [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) too, but I don't remember which chapter.

As regards the function above, I'm a bit puzzled. What is the most concise way to write it without using the `do` expression? The best I could come up with is

```hs
solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double
solveRPN s = foldM step [] (words s) >>= \x -> case x of
                                               [y] -> Just y
                                               _   -> Nothing
```

but I was hoping in something cleaner, as this one is pretty noisy for 2 reasons:

- it uses a lambda
- it uses the `case` expression, which doesn't look much nicer than a `if`-`then`-`else`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226842/how-to-pattern-match-an-intermediate-value-in-haskell/59226926#59226926) is related to the present one.

I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803061/can-this-function-be-written-in-point-free-style-if-not-why/) which actually highlights the basic issue in this one:

*How do I pull the `head` out of a list and succeed only for singleton lists?*

And this has nothing to do with the `Maybe` that wraps the result in `solveRPN`.

### Update

The [answer I accepted there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803320/5825294) proposes a clear solution the question above:

```hs
func :: [a] -> a
func = foldr1 (const (const undefined))
```

which can be used to write easily `solveRPN` in pointfree style:

```hs
solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double
solveRPN st = foldM foldingFunction [] (words st) >>= Just . foldr1 (const (const undefined))
```

However, this absolutely unsatisfying, as it does not fully take advantage of the `Maybe` monad, failing at runtime instead of returning `Nothing` when the output is incorrect.

I think that playing around with that could lead me or someone else to answer my original question without `do`/`case`/helpers.

Comment: Not many real options here. You could use a monad comprehension (which is `do` in disguise). Or, for a marginal gain, you could use `\case [y] -> ... ; _ -> ...` Desugaring `do` with patterns leads to a more verbose code: that's why the sugar is nice to have.

Comment: Regarding your last point, `case` is a lot nicer than if/then/else. It brings the pattern's constituent parts into scope when it succeeds, whereas the `then` part of an `if` just has the knowledge that some Boolean expression is true.

Answer (score 1):

The [desugaring of `do` notation](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) specified in the Haskell Report actually includes a pattern match in order to handle pattern match failure with `fail`, now specified in the `MonadFail` typeclass. It may be written as a `case` or as a function.

> ```
> do {e}                 =  e
> do {e;stmts}           =  e >> do {stmts}
> do {p <- e; stmts}     =  let ok p = do {stmts}
>                               ok _ = fail "..."
>                             in e >>= ok
> do {let decls; stmts}  =  let decls in do {stmts}
> ```

So in your example, that could look like this.

```
solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double  
solveRPN st = foldM foldingFunction [] (words st) >>= \ x -> case x of
    [result] -> return result
    _ -> fail "Pattern match failure in do expression at file:line:col"
```

(And of course `fail message :: Maybe a` is just `Nothing`.)

You can make this slightly more concise with `LambdaCase` to avoid the extra variable.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double  
solveRPN st = foldM foldingFunction [] (words st) >>= \ case
    [result] -> return result
    _ -> fail "Pattern match failure in do expression at file:line:col"
```

That’s the standard desugaring, but if you want to golf this further, you can use a helper function. The standard `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a` works if you want to allow non-singleton lists.

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double  
solveRPN st = foldM foldingFunction [] (words st) >>= listToMaybe
```

There is no standard `singletonToMaybe` but you can easily write one.

```
singletonToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a
singletonToMaybe [x] = Just x
singletonToMaybe _   = Nothing

-- or:

singletonToMaybe xs = guard (isSingleton xs) *> listToMaybe xs

isSingleton = null . drop 1
```

Then write the function in point-free style using the monadic composition operators `<=<` or `>=>`.

```
solveRPN :: String -> Maybe Double  
solveRPN = singletonToMaybe <=< foldM foldingFunction [] . words
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the last proposed solution is actually faulty, as it allows a non-`Nothing` result even if the list piped through `<=<` contains more than one element, wichi is contrast with what I have just bolded in my question.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: Right you are; I’ve added some clarification on that point but I don’t think much improvement is possible without helper functions that, sadly, aren’t defined in `base`.